# How to set the name of a form without a class?

Tags: symfony

Here is written how to set the name of a form with a class:

http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/forms.html#creating-form-classes

but how to set the name of this form?

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($defaultData)
    ->add('name', 'text')
    ->add('email', 'email')
    ->getForm();
```

Well, I'm trying to get post parameters after submitting it this way:

```
$postData = $request->request->get('form_name');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there any reason why you don't just do:

```
$data = $form->getData();
```

Comment: Yes, that works, but I have to redeclare the form in the action called by form submitting.. :)

Answer (score 44):

I would like to bring some more precision. At least, for the most recent version of Symfony (2.1), the correct symtax (documented on the API) is:

```
<?php

     public FormBuilderInterface createNamedBuilder(string $name, string|FormTypeInterface $type = 'form', mixed $data = null, array $options = array(), FormBuilderInterface $parent = null)
```

It is important because you can still pass options to the FormBuilder.
For a more concrete example:

```
<?php

 $form = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamedBuilder('user', 'form',  null, array(
    'constraints' => $collectionConstraint,
))
->add('name', 'text')
->add('email', 'email')
->getForm();
```

Comment: In `Symfony 3.1`, if you also want to set other options, the solution is: `$this->get('form.factory')->createNamedBuilder('yourFormName', FormType::class, null, ['option'=>'value']`

Answer (score 14):

There is no shortcut method for this purpose. Instead you have to access the method `createNamedBuilder` in the form factory:

```
$this->get('form.factory')->createNamedBuilder('form', 'form_name', $defaultData)
    ->add('name', 'text')
    ->add('email', 'email')
    ->getForm();
```

Comment: As far as I can see this is still valid for Symfony2.3, am I right? Still no shortcut for this.

Comment: Just noted that in Symfony 2.3 the parameters are the other way around ... so its now `(name, type, defaults, options)` .. [see the docs](http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/Form/FormFactory.html#method_createNamedBuilder)

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Symfony 3.1, the field types have changed to use their explicit class (`FormType`, `TextType`, and `EmailType`) and the parameter  position for the value of the form `name` attribute has switched places with the `FormType` parameter in the [`createNamedBuilder` function](http://api.symfony.com/3.1/Symfony/Component/Form/FormFactoryInterface.html#method_createNamedBuilder).

```
$this->get('form.factory')
  ->createNamedBuilder('form_name', FormType::class, $defaultData)
  ->add('name', TextType::class)
  ->add('email', EmailType::class)
  ->getForm();
```

Answer (score 1):

In version 2.4.1 of Symfony, the solution is:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder ( NULL, array ( 'attr' => array ( 'name' => 'myFormName', 'id' => 'myFormId' ) ) )
            ->add (..
```

You can also set other form attributes this way, but I've not tried. Replace NULL with your data if you want.

Comment: This doesn't work as it's rendered as `<form name="form" name="myFormName" />`.