# Handle two forms in one Controller with Symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine

Hey I am saving every page in two different languages on my website. I want to manage my pages with an admin area that I am developing with symfony2 at the moment.

Following controller code is able to display two forms on the same page containing the right data from the database. One form to manage the DE language and another for EN:

View:

```
<form action="{{ path('admin_about') }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(formEN) }}>
            {{ form_widget(formEN) }}

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn btn-warning" naem="EN">Save</button>
        </form>

        <form action="{{ path('admin_about') }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(formDE) }}>
            {{ form_widget(formDE) }}

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn btn-warning" name="DE">Save</button>
        </form>
```

Controller:
    public function aboutAction(Request $request)
    {

```
    $pageEN = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('MySitePublicBundle:Page')
    ->findOneBy(array('idName' => 'about', 'lang' => 'EN'));

    $pageDE = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('MySitePublicBundle:Page')
    ->findOneBy(array('idName' => 'about', 'lang' => 'DE'));

    if (!$pageDE) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('About page (DE) not found.');
    }

    if (!$pageEN) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('About page (EN) not found.');
    }

    $formDE = $this->createFormBuilder($pageDE)
        ->add('title', 'text')
        ->add('content', 'text')
        ->getForm();

    $formEN = $this->createFormBuilder($pageEN)
        ->add('title', 'text')
        ->add('content', 'text')
        ->getForm();

    //Save Form here

    return $this->render('MySitePublicBundle:Admin:about.html.twig', array(
        'aboutPageDE' => $pageDE, 'aboutPageEN' => $pageEN, 'formDE' => $formDE->createView(), 'formEN' => $formEN->createView(),
    ));
}
```

**My Question is: How to save the form that has been used out of one controller?**

Comment: You may wish to look at [form classes](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#creating-form-classes) and handle the translations there. That way you'd only have one form to worry about persisting (and wouldn't have to duplicate the `FormBuilder` code for each translation.

Comment: I don't see how this solves my problem?! Or is it just for the sake of don't repeat yourself? :-)

Comment: Oh, you're looking for how to save them in general? I'll add an answer...

Answer (score 2):

Based on the [Forms and Doctrine](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#forms-and-doctrine) section of the Symfony2 Docs (or in your case, since you're [not using a Form class](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#using-a-form-without-a-class)) --

So where you have `//save form here` assuming you've set up `MySitePublicBundle:Page` to save the `Title` and `Content` (and has the normal getters/setters).

```
if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
    $form->bindRequest($request);

    // data is an array with "title" and "content" keys
    $data = $form->getData();

    // You'll need to have some switch depending on which language you're dealing
    // with... (unless its both, then just repeat for $pageDE)

    $pageEn->setTitle($data['title']);
    $pageEn->setContent($data['content']);

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $em->persist($pageEn);
    $em->flush();
}
```

Comment: Alright I managed to save it. But I am struggling with the switch. Thank you so far.

Comment: By the way I am using an entity class!

Comment: What about adding a hidden field that tells you the language on each form, then doing `if($data['language'] == "EN") { $pageEN->... } else { $pageDE->... }` as your switch?

Comment: I can't belive symfony has no way to deal with something like that -.- Why is forms made so complex then?

Answer (score 1):

In your controller you could test if the request contains the forms, such as:

```
if($this->getRequest()->get('form1')) {
    //
} elseif($this->getRequest()->get('form2')) {
    //
}
```

Comment: I set the DOM-Id of the forms to 'form1' and 'form2' for this code. It doesn't find them :-(

Comment: It's not the ID that matters here but the form name. You can override the getName() method of your form types to return the same values that you're testing for in your controller.

Comment: DOM parameter 'name' doesn't work either. How do you overwrite the form type? And why would I do that. Sorry for asking those newbie quetsions. I was aiming for the easiest solution and then refactoring it..

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't realise you're not using a form class. In which case you can't override the getName() method, and I'm not sure how the form name is set. There's likely a much better way to do this, but you can find out the form name(s) by dumping the contents of $this->getRequest() to screen, or in the dev environment you can also view the request data via the web profiler.

Comment: The form submits only the _Token value. No name value! Am I the first one trying this? :-/

Comment: I think the last answer here should help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7796010/how-to-set-the-name-of-a-form-without-a-class