# Symfony2 Forms: Set name of form without entity

Tags: php, forms, symfony, attributes

I create a form in my controller without entity like following:

```
$defaultData = array('message' => 'Assign');
$form_assign = $this->createFormBuilder($defaultData)
  ->add('team', 'text', array('label' => 'Team'))
  ->add('create', 'button', array('label' => 'Create'))
  ->getForm();
```

Now when i render the form in my view with

```
{{ form(form_assign) }}
```

The name of the form is allways "form", like this:

```
<form name="form" method="post" action>
```

How do i change the name-attribute of the form?
I work with Symfony version 2.4.2

(i have read [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21041724) on a similar question and tried it out, but it didnt worked for me.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the `createNamedBuilder` function :

```
$defaultData = array('message' => 'Assign');
$form_assign = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamedBuilder('your-custom-name', 'form', $defaultData, array())
    ->add('team', 'text', array('label' => 'Team'))
    ->add('create', 'button', array('label' => 'Create'))
    ->getForm();
```

Comment: When I do this, with name `custom_name` I get a form named `custom_name` but then inputs with names like `form[first_name]` which does not compute :)